# Github actions error ssh: handshake failed: unable to authenticate using appleboy/ssh-action

Tags: laravel, ssh, github-actions, cicd

I am using appleboy/ssh-action to deploy my laravel App to my digital ocean droplet. I have set my private ssh key, user and ip adress as secrets in the repo and also i have supplied my public ssh key in github and also wrote my deploy logic in my .yml file but somehow the action fails giving me the error  ***ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain***
i can clone github repos from the server which means github is aware of my public ssh key.

Here is my yml file

```
  - name: Checkout of the repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Deploy to testing server
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST}}
      username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME}}
      key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}
      script: |
        cd /pathOfTheProject
        php artisan down
        git stash
        git checkout testing
        git pull
        npm install --force
        npm run build
        composer update --optimize-autoloader
        php artisan migrate --force
        php artisan optimize:clear
        php artisan optimize
        php artisan up
```